# Updating atlassian profile image using rest

Tags: rest, jira, confluence

Is it possible to update a profile picture in Atlassian using a rest call?

I have read the documentation and it seems like you can update the profile but there is nothing about the picture.

[Reference to profile REST API documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/admin/user-management/rest/api-group-profile/).

```
curl --request GET \
    --url 'https://api.atlassian.com/users/{account_id}/manage/profile' \
    --header 'Authorization: Bearer <access_token>' \
    --header 'Accept: application/json'
```